# Adding android application name at build time

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to create an android module that will be included into multiple projects. It will contain general information about the projects such as application name, build date, git branch name and so on..
I have managed to find solutions for most of the fileds using some java code in the gradle.build file, except for the application name.
These values are stored in static final fields in a class.
Is there a way to find the application name or the parent pkg name at build time ?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thx!